# Is it possible to get Windows Azure SDK 1.7 projects to run in 2.3 emulator?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-emulator

Installed Windows Azure SDK 2.3 on my dev machine and now an older VS 2010 Azure 1.7 SDK solution (June 2012) fails to launch with the following error:

*Windows Azure Tools: Error: The installed Windows Azure Emulator does not support the role binaries. Please install the latest Windows Azure Emulator and try again.
Windows Azure Tools: The system is missing a prerequisite to execute the service. Please see the release notes.*

Is it possible to get 1.7 projects to run using the 2.3 Emulator, or do I need to uninstall the new emulator and re-install the old one? Upgrading the project is currently not an option.

Comment: Do you still intend to use VS 2010?

Comment: Can upgrade to VS2012 or 2013, not a problem. Upgrading Azure SDK not feasible just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDK 1.8 introduced side-by-side capabilities for the SDK and emulator such that you could have both SDKs installed at the same time.  SDK 1.7 did not have this same compatibility so you will not be able to run your SDK 1.7 project on a machine with SDK 2.3 installed.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. For some reason, I was thinking 1.7 already allowed running side-by-side.

Comment: So the only option is "uninstall", until we're ready to upgrade?